# Auto logon windows at a specific time using c#

Tags: c#

Auto logon windows at a specific time. How can i do this in c# ?
Any ideas please...

Purpose : I need to perform some tasks at a specific time in midnight. which needs the windows to be logged on.

Comment: Can you explain more.. I am sure there should be an alternative solution ;-)

Comment: @Shoban, I want to programmaticly login to windows user account using c# for achieving the purpose i stated above. How can i do this ?

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to log in to have an interactive session. You say you need to perform some task. Do YOU perform the task (interactively) or is it simply some other piece of software that runs at midnight. If it's software, why does it need an interactive session? We need some more details to give qualified answers.

Comment: @FrankBollack, I need to run a software which requires the windows to be logged on. Thats the nature of it and its classified. This is the reason i want the system to be unlocked automatically at a point of time. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Scheduled Task](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569/en-us). On the task panel you un-check the option "only after the current user logs on". That's it.

#### Update

So to make this with a little more explanation:

This was your question:

> Purpose : I need to perform some tasks at a specific time in midnight. which needs the windows to be logged on

So to get this to work, you have to split your task a little bit up. At first write your task that should be performed (a batch-script, a self-written application, a third-party application with a configuration file or some command line parameters, etc.).

If you got your task up and you can run it on a single finger tip (e.g. click on a lnk file on your desktop, enter a single command on the command-line, etc.), it's time to automate your task for a specific time schedule. For this purpose Microsoft already provided a powerful tool, called `Scheduled Tasks`. It is located in the Control Panel. Here you can define Tasks which should be started with dozens of options and time plans. Just step through the wizard and after that make a double click or right click - Properties on the created task. Now step through all the TabPages and take a close look on all the available options. Everything you need can be solved here.

#### Update 2

So after reading your comment (and a few other):

> If my system is locked, then i need it to get unlocked at a point of time

My first question would be: **What do you mean with *locked***?

There are two states in which a system can be locked:

1. The system is freshly started, no session is running and you need to provide a username and a password to get a session to run.
2. A user has already logged in and the system is currently locked (cause the user pressed <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, the screen saver is configured to lock, etc.).

The difference between those two states is, in the first you need to provide a username and a password, in the second one you only need to provide the password only.

What both have in common is you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> to get the needed Dialog and this is not possible from an application.

If you really need to log-on or unlock the screen at a specific time you should start a search about `gina.dll` and how to replace or enhance it so that you can send a message to it, to do whatever you like. But this dll replacement can't be done in C#. It has do be done in C/C++. And i forgot, that the gina.dll approach only works on XP. For Vista/Win7 they changed the log-on process and the procedure to intercept it, but a search for the provided keywords should reveal the needed informations.

Comment: @Oliver, i dont understand what you are saying.. Is that i dint frame the question properly or u dint understand it properly ?

Comment: @Anuya: If you wonder that, then it's obvioius that your questions allows for a wide interpretation. Do you want a to log in to have an interactive session running or do you simply want to run a task at a specific time with under a specific user account. The latter one can be achieved as Oliver stated.

Comment: @ Frank Bollack, i want to run a interactive session after logging in automatically

Comment: @Oliver, Again...i want windows to be logged on at a specific time and i dont want to start the tasks. If my system is locked, then i need it to get unlocked at a point of time. Thanks

Comment: @Anuya: Do we talk about a LOCKED system (user already logged in) or a system where no user is LOGGED IN?

Comment: @Frank Bollack, This is about the system where it is just started up and the user has not logged in. I want to unlock the windows using a c#

Comment: @Oliver, You are right...I meant both the scenarios. There is no way to do it with c# ? I am using windows XP

Comment: @Anuya: No, there is no way to replace the logon mechanism (gina.dll or pendant in Win7) through a .net assembly. You have to code a C-dll which unlocks the screen also through some other signal (event, named pipe, etc.). But this other signal can then also come from a C# application.

Answer (score 0):

look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WinAutoLogin.aspx) thread.

---

You can replace your app with userinit.exe.
it runs before Explorer.

Comment: i tried using that already. But i quit using that because the passwords and usernames are stored in plain text inside registry.

Comment: Also my machine is OS Hardened. When i try using that code...It is showing me a warning message, that i am trying to violate the rules according to OS Hardening.

Comment: Can u be more elaborate on UserInit.exe ? Please, never heard that before :)

Comment: @Anuya, UserInit.exe is in hidden folder in system32 that named dllcache.
userinit.exe is a key process in the Windows operating system. On boot-up it manages the different start up sequences needed, such as establishing network connection and starting up the Windows shell. This program is important for the stable and secure running of your computer and should not be terminated.\r